# Thread Pool Execution Order and Passing Future to Another Thread

Tags: multithreading, service, execution, pool

I would like to create a thread pool with two threads. I would like to ensure the first threads get executed first and after the completion of first thread then the second thread get start. Besides this, I need to pass Future result from first thread into second thread.

Any idea how to do this?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand the requirement fully.  If you have two tasks, and one must follow the other, why do you need more than one thread per two tasks?  Define a CombinedTask that calls both sub-tasks, one after the other, and submit to any old threadpool.

Comment: Avoid using thread in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is not suitable to use thread. Thus, avoid using thread.